# Play Audio when an Image is clicked in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, avfoundation

I have set up UICollectionView with an UIImage and UILabel in a cell. When the user taps in the cell, it should play the specific audio associated with the image. I have implemented following code to play audio after specifying `import AVFoundation`

```
var vegImageArray = ["broccoli","carrot","eggplant", "garlic", "onion", "spinach", "tomato"]

var vegLabelArray = ["Broccoli", "Carrot", "Eggplant", "Garlic", "Onion", "Spinach", "Tomato"]

var vegSoundArray = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4", "sound5", "sound6", "sound7"]



func playsound() {
    

    do {
        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound1", withExtension: "mp3") {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
        }
        else {
            print("No file exists")
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Can't play error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    audioPlayer?.play()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let filename = vegSoundArray[indexPath.item]

playSound()}
```

The problem is when I run this code all the cells are playing only "sound1" instead of brocolli playing sound1, carrot with sound2, eggplant with sound 3 and so on.
And when I replace it with following code it plays nothing.

```
let filename = vegSoundArray[indexPath.item]

        do {
                if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "mp3")
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: Make sure you are getting the correct sound value from the array. Try to add debugger and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is playing sound1 every time because you have hard-coded that in `forResource: "sound1"`. You should pass the filename variable into playsound(), and use that as the `forResource` arg

Comment: Yes I have seen that ,the problem is when I am replacing the "sound1" with "filename" in  forResource its not playing anything. Also, when I am trying to pass filename variable in playSound() its giving me an error "Use of unresolved identifier". What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Make sure you don't put quotes around it, otherwise it will look for a file literally named "filename.mp3". Like so: `if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "mp3")`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! That was the mistake I was doing, just removing the quotes solved this.